# Set restrictions by ReceivedTime on mail list

Tags: vba, outlook

Am trying to read mails that received only today. Below is the code where am restricting but its throwing an condition not valid error. The same is working fine when I gave a condition like `unread = True`.

```
Set myItems = myItems.Restrict("DateValue[ReceivedTime]='" & Format(DateValue(Now),"ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'")
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two problems.

1. You have "DateValue[ReceivedTime]" rather than "[ReceivedTime]".
2. You are restricting emails to those received at exactly midnight today rather than those received after midnight.

Try this code:

```
Sub RestrictByDate()

  Dim FmtToday As String
  Dim FldrInbox As Folder
  Dim MailItemsToday As Items
  Dim MailItemCrnt As MailItem

  FmtToday = Format(DateValue(Now()), "ddddd h:nn AMPM")

  ' #### Replace "xxxx" with the name of the store containing the target Inbox
  Set FldrInbox = Session.Folders("xxxx").Folders("Inbox")

  Set MailItemsToday = FldrInbox.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" & FmtToday & "'")

  Debug.Print "Number of emails received today=" & MailItemsToday.Count
  For Each MailItemCrnt In MailItemsToday
    With MailItemCrnt
      Debug.Print .ReceivedTime & " " & .Subject
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tony. It really helped                                          
  'Dim FmtToday As String                                                                        
  FmtToday = Format(DateValue(Now()), "ddddd h:nn AMPM")               
  Set MailItemsToday = FldrInbox.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" & FmtToday & "'")' . Have changed my code with this and it worked.